# Why the overloaded method with const reference return value is not called?

Tags: c++, reference, polymorphism, overloading, const-reference

Consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
    private:
    int x;
    public:
    int& get_ref() {
        cerr << "non const" << endl;
        return x;
    }

    const int& get_ref() const {
        cerr << "const" << endl;
        return x;
    }
};

int main () {
    A a;
    a.get_ref() = 10;

    cout << a.get_ref() << endl;

    const int& y = a.get_ref();

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the second and third calls to `a.get_ref()` to run the second version of `get_ref()` method (and output `const` on the standard error).    But it looks like always the first version is called.  How can I implement two different 'getter's and make sure that the proper version is called based on the context?  I.e., at least for the third call

```
const int& y = a.get_ref();
```

the second version is executed?  (A non-elegant solution would be to use different names e.g. `get_ref` and `get_const_ref` but I am trying to see if that can be avoided.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overload resolution doesn't depend on return values, but only arguments, including the object to be called on for member function. `a` is a non-const object, then for `a.get_ref()`, the non-const member function will always be called.

You can cast it to `const` for the const version to be called:

```
const_cast<const A&>(a).get_ref();
```

---

BTW: Giving them different names is not a bad idea. That's why we have [`std::cbegin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::cend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) in STL.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  So, this, in particular, means that any call to `get_ref` from inside the class will be resolved to the first (non-const) version (unless we cast `this` to `const` similarly to what you suggested).  Am I right?

Comment: @PBM More precisely, any call to `get_ref` from the member functions of the class, the resolution depends on `this` points to `const` or `non-const`, i.e. the member function being called firstly is `const` or not. So inside a `const` member function, when calling `get_ref`, the const `get_ref` will be called; inside a non-const member function, non-const `get_ref` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Overload resolution is concerned only with the arguments of the call (including the implicit argument for `this`). The expression `a.get_ref()` must evaluate to the same overload regardless of what happens with its returned value. That is fundamental in C++, and there's nothing you can do about it.

If you want to call the `const`-qualified version, use a `const`-qualified object expression:

```
const int& y = const_cast<const A&>(a).get_ref();
```

Comment: There are of course workaround possible, based on the concrete situation you want to handle. If you specify *why* you want such behaviour, I might come up with a workaround for it. It will be ugly and discouraged, but might be possible.